# google colabであるテキストファイル内で特定の文字以前の文字列を削除するコマンドを教えてください。

Tags: linux, google-colaboratory

以下の文字列がテキストファイル内に保存されていて、最初の$より以前の文字列をコマンドで削除したいです。
/content/shoes7.pdf:$pdf$4*
↓
$pdf$4*

Comment: `$` 記号が二つ含まれているようですが、どのような結果になることを期待しているのかも記載があると意図が伝わりやすいと思います。

Comment: 訂正しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: google colabのエディタで削除したいのでしょうか？ダウンロードしてから何かのエディタを使って削除したいのでしょうか？使用するエディタによって方法が変わると思います。

Comment: こっちに回答付いてますね。
https://teratail.com/questions/314141#reply-438266